# Joomla mootools-core and jquery problem

Tags: jquery-ui, joomla, mootools, joomla1.6

I'm using jquery us-slider and it has conflict with joomla 1.6 mootools-core.js when this file is being removed ui-slider works fine.

I'm not sure were is the problem jquery code:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#slider-ad_price").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 100000,
    step: 50,
    values: [1, 100000],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        jQuery("#ad_price").val(ui.values[0]);
        jQuery("#ad_priceb").val(ui.values[1]);
    }
});
```

});

Thanks

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library and added jQuery.noConflict(); right at the end of the jQuery library code after the last semi-colon?

Answer (score 1):

I rewritten your code:

```
$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#slider-ad_price").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 100000,
    step: 50,
    values: [1, 100000],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#ad_price").val(ui.values[0]);
      $("#ad_priceb").val(ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

This makes jQuery to work even there are other JS frameworks in it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a problem if you use Mootools with closures and "Dollar Safe Mode" mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode and jQuery no conflict. You could also try write your slider as a Mootools class.